# AWT ActionListener as abstract class

Tags: java, class, awt, abstract, final

I have a program with a AWT GUI in Java. My problem is that I have a lots of abstract Classes (ActionListener) in this program. Within this abstract classes I need to call attributes from the main-class. So, at the moment I must all needed attributes set as final. That is not nice. My question is how can I call the attributes from the main-class (without set this as final). What's the better code style?

For example:

```
public class mainClass {
    TextField field1 = new TextField(10);
    (...)
    Button connect = new Button("Connecting...");
    (...)
    connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex) {
            methodFromTheMainClass(field1.getText());
            // How can I call the method methodFromTheMainClass?
         }
    });

    private void methodFromTheMainClass(String fieldContent) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Thanks for help, and sorry for my English. :-/

Comment: What's not nice about `final`?

Comment: mhh at the moment a lots of attributes are final. I do not know if that is good. And I do not know how I call a method from the main class.

Comment: `final` fields are GOOD! The compiler can make a huge number of optimizations with them, including stuff about memory visibility. Really, there even is an option in Eclipse to mark all non-mutable fields as final on a save. But if you insist on not having them final, you can create a private class and then pass your fields as constructor parameters to them.

Comment: Okay, thanks! - But how can I call methods from the main class. I can set these not as final?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand you, what do you mean by "call methods from the main class"?

Comment: Is `field1` an instance member?

Comment: I have in my actionPerformed method (within the abstract class) a call to a method they is in the main-class. On the top there is the edited example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `final` keyword is a pretty much good solution *almost everywhere* where it can be used
In your case it's totally O.K. to use the `final` keyword.

But if you strongly want to make fields not `final`(or due to your business logic needs) just create an inner (non-static) class, that contains all your fields that accessed from local abstract classes.

Here is an example:

```
public class YourClass { 

    private class Container {
        private TextField field = new TextField();
        private Button connectButton = new Button("Connecting...");
    }

    private final Container container = new Container();

    private void establishConnection() {
        container.connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // connection code here

                container.field.setText("Connection established"); // access to an inner class
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! - Can I set methods from the main class as final?

Comment: If it make sance that's fine. You can make whole class `final` if it's not inherited instead of set every method as `final`.

Comment: Thank's for the example. That's seems like a good solution. But is it good code style?

Comment: Nope, it's better to create several `final` fields instead of one container class, because in this case it's useless. It's just an example as it can be if you really need to hide lots of `final` fields.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And how I can call a method in the main-class? - See my edited code in the question. At the moment I must set the method as static only then can I call the method. Is that good, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's better to create a class that encapsulates your method and set that metod non-static.